# String and file replacement from another file

Tags: python, unix

I have two text files, man.txt and job.txt

In man.txt I have

```
abc = "pqr"
abc1 = "xyz"
```

In job.txt I have

```
pqrst
xyz
```

I want to find and replace `"pqr"` in man.txt with `"pqrst"` in Python or Unix

I know by abc that pqr is to replace(abc is specific)

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you supposed to know that you need to replace `pqr` based on those files?

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by using `fileinput`.

```
import fileinput  

with fileinput.FileInput("man.txt", inplace=True) as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line.replace('abc = "pqr"', 'abc = "pqrst"'), end='')
```

Comment: i Don't know wether it is pqrst or pqrxst or pqrpy. I mean I only know the starting initials

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: i only know that in one of line in job.txt i have a line whose initials are "pqr"(means the string that comes after equals to in man.txt)